# Magento united parcel service XML not working

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

[image: My UPS settings]

The above image have my ups xml configuration screen shot. I filled all the required fields and check all the possible ways. But in not works in magento 1.7.

Using ups type **United parcel service** it works fine, but not works in **XML ups type**.

Any one have idea to short out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Enabled logging and check your logs under `/var/log`.  See what the responses are from UPS are.  That will tell you the exact reason it's not working.

Comment: Try this URL http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled the debug mode , so check for in the `var/log` folder for `shipping_ups.log` file where you will get the request and response xml.

You can check if you are getting any error in your response xml.